# Complex object grammar and other things

Tags: syntactic-analysis, direct-objects, predicate

I've seen a number of different phrases in different books describing the action of closing a door, and I'm not quite sure that I fully understand the grammar behind them. For example:

**(1)** [He] clicked the door shut. / [You] push the door open.

**(2)** The door clicked shut. / The door clicked open.

The first two pretty much remind me of *complex object* construction, but I am confused by the atypical verbs as "click" and "push". As for the second one, I want to specify whether I'm right that it's just the sequence "noun + verb + adjective" as sth like "The house stands empty" etc.

Could someone make it clear? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maria, when you have a minute, look at the edit to your question. See if you understand the reasons for changing the way you said things.

Comment: You also probably want to ask most questions like this at http://ell.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Ily, thank you for editing and the link.  Next time I'll ask something that stupid  there)

Comment: It isn't a stupid question. It's just one that seems more helpful for ESL students such as yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia and Wiktionary still don't know that "complex objects" exist. [As far as I can tell from cursory googling](https://english.ucalgary.ca/grammar/course/sentence/2_2b.htmhttps://english.ucalgary.ca/grammar/course/sentence/2_2b.htm), it's just a term some teachers use to describe any object with some modifiers attached. It's not a very useful concept, since there are several completely different constructions that make predicates more complicated. Using one term as a catch-all can create a false sense of understanding.

In any case, **it looks like the term for this construction is [secondary predicate](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/slam-the-door-shut.2686608/)**. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate) also seems to group several ideas under that heading, but they all have the structure of *action verb* + [*object*] + *adjective*:

- All men are created equal.
- His speech left me cold.
- She shot him dead.
- He ran himself ragged.

In this case, *push* is a bog standard verb for doors; *click* (=*made ~ go 'click'*) is just a descriptive word for whatever action caused that noise to be made. In this case, there's probably a light latch.

In your examples, the extra adjective at the end is describing the state resulting from the action: *He ~ the door* [*and then it was*] *shut*... *He ~ the door* [*and then it was*] *open*... You could also think about the structure in a few other ways: *He ~ the door* [*so that it was*] *shut*... *She ~ the door* [*until it was*] *open*...

Comment: @Ily , I have also never had any special sympathy for this concept. But I do remember that "I make him do something" and "I expect him to be honest" are related to that weird notion. That is just what I was taught. My apologies, up untill now, I thought that it was sth generally accepted and common. As for this case, I confused "adjective" at the end with the " infinitive", but, thanks to your examples, it seems that everything is in its place now. Thank you for your suggestions and  a nice explanations here!